`"Hello ".split(" ")` produces an array with two items
I have, surprisingly, not found an explanation for this.
In Kotlin, the .split function normally takes a delimiter and separates a String by that delimiter, returning a list of results and discarding the delimiter.
However, consider the following:
val arr = "Hello ".split(" ")
println("size = ${arr.size}") // size 2
println(arr)                  // [Hello, ]

Why, in the above instance, does the resulting list have two items, including the delimiter?

To close voters: this very clearly isn't a typo

It is not actually including your delimiter.  It is just an empty string of length 0, not " " of length 1.
If you had
"Hello+".split("+")

it would also yield [Hello, ].
When you use split() it splits the string into strings around the delimiter.
So, splitting "Hello " by " " yields TWO strings before and after the last letter, which is "Hello" and "".

You're also getting the empty string created by splitting on that whitespace. If you tried splitting " hello " you'd see the size be 3.
To avoid this, first trim excess whitespace and then split.
val arr = "Hello ".trim(' ').split(" ")
println("size = ${arr.size}") 
println(arr)                  


Although the other answers already explain how split works, OP's confusion likely stems from the space in [Hello, ], assuming it is the second item.
arr is a list, and by printing it it is converted to a string. Whatever the content, a list's string representation will always have the following form:
[<item1>, <item2>, <item3>, <item4>]

and so on. The spaces here are not the items, they are simply part of the delimiter to make the list more readable: A comma followed by a space.
Your actual list contains two items, the string "Hello" and the empty string "". The double quotes are omitted in the output (again, for the sake of readability), so instead of
["Hello", ""]

you get
[Hello, ]

